# No Internet connection- Ionic

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I work on a Ionic Application and I've a problem when my app has no connection.

This code works when the app is already open and lost connection to the Internet. But when I open the app with no connection already, it doesn't work (just shows a blank screen after splashscreen):

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    var type = $cordovaNetwork.getNetwork()
    var isOnline = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline()
    var isOffline = $cordovaNetwork.isOffline()

    // listen for Online event
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online', function(event, networkState){
      var onlineState = networkState;
    })

    // listen for Offline event
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline', function(event, networkState){
      var offlineState = networkState;
      $ionicPopup.alert({
      title: "Pas d'accès à Internet!", 
      content: "Votre smartphone ne semble pas être connecté à Internet. Vous ne pouvez pas profiter de vos boissons offertes."
    })
})
// Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
// for form inputs)
```

Any clue to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's Possible to make a request to the application initialization and crack your script. Check, please, that if it happens.